# New timeline application tab width and logo

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

It seems the new Timeline for Page will let applications tabs run in a wider canvas. Right now, my tab applications are still running in an iframe of 520px width. Anyone knows if there is a way to change that?

Also, the required app image is still 75x75px. I hope Facebook will soon allow us to upload images in the format of the new tabs which seems to be about 110x75px.

Answer (score 10):

Check your tab settings (`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<APPID>/summary`)for the "Page Tab Width" field. Your two options are 520 and 810px.

Comment: And what about the new tab image format? I can't find the option to upload it yet.

Comment: I think you do that from the page itself. Expand the app view, and then hover over one of the images and you'll see a pencil icon in the top right hand corner of the image.

Answer (score 5):

The documented tab width is 810px but I'm measuring the containing div as 779px. Not sure yet what is the official width, but I'd go with 810px since that's available in the app settings.

The tab icon dimensions are 111x74px and Jimmy is right--you have to add the larger image on the page itself. Installing the large icon on the FB app will restrict it to 75x75px. Once the tab is on the FB page, expand the favorites and hover over the tab, click the pencil icon and go to Edit Settings. You can add a custom tab image that's 111x74px.

Jeremy

Comment: That's good to know! But it still sucks for generic apps like mine that can be used by any page admin. I should be able to set a default 111x74px icon for the app that the admin can change. Hope this will soon be an option.

Comment: I had to go to 'Edit Page' then 'Apps' to get to the settings to add the new wide icon.

Comment: I've found other devs reporting the 810/779px discrepancy as a Facebook bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/179918418787576?browse=search_4f4fc66668f396f05113928. It appears 779px is the actual width on the page.

Comment: Rafi Jacoby's method to add a custom tab icon also works, I tested it just now. FWIW, the new Timeline layout seems to bury the Edit Page link within a submenu in the admin panel.

Comment: Looks like Facebook has fixed this bug and the tab width is now 810px.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the logo size is concerned, here is what I'm observing:

It defaults to the 75x75 pixel app icon. So here you're limited to a width of 75px.

But you can customize the tab image and use the full space on a per-page basis by going to https://developers.facebook.com/pages/tab_image?pid=_PAGE_ID_&app_id=_APP_ID_

I found this out from this SO answer:
[What is the size of new Facebook Page Tab App icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782945/what-is-the-size-of-new-facebook-page-tab-app-icon#answers-header)

I would really like to be able to have a full sized image that doesn't have to be set on a per page basis.

#### Update 5/7/2012

You can now upload a 111 x 74px image for all tab instances from the app settings page. It's called the "Page Tab Image". (It still defaults to the app icon if this isn't set.)

You can still customize the page tab image on a per page basis with the URL above or through the app API. The property is either `custom_icon` or `custom_icon_url`. [Read the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post showing how to edit a tab image.  It goes step by step, very clearly illustrated:
http://www.wendymoore.net/2012/03/facebook-fan-page-timeline-how-to-edit-a-tab-image/

The simple answer is yes, you can put a 111x74 tab image directly on the fan page, not the apps page, by clicking on the triangle to the far right, mouse hover the tab to open the context menu and choose Edit Settings.