# What is the size of new Facebook Page Tab App icon

Tags: icons, size, facebook-page

I have been trying to adjust the icon size to 75*75 but on my facebook page it gets compressed. I have seen apps icon for http://www.facebook.com/cocacola, trying to figure how did they do it, as i failed trying different sizes.

Answer (score 9):

111x74px - you can set it if you go the your fan-page -> Settings -> Appliation -> Application Settings (of the tab). there you find a link to change exactly this image.

or you can use this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/pages/tab_image?pid=_PAGE_ID_&app_id=_APP_ID_

Answer (score 3):

And make it a jpg a png format gives not a smooth result

Comment: Please tell me, how come a lossy image format like JPG give a smoother result than a lossless one like PNG?

Comment: @JoseFaeti (Not sure if this is the issue, but it can be a possible explaination) Can be caused by a PNG being recompressed with FBs quality setting to a JPEG, while an existing JPEG is just added and not recompressed.

Answer (score 0):

111px by 74px

You can edit the image by selecting the 'edit' option on the tab then going to 'change tab image'